# Should I hold connections or should I create new connections everytime?

Tags: java, sockets

Should the server keep a socket connection and wait for new data or should the server close a socket connection and the client creates a new connection everytime he need to send data?

Comment: Depends on how frequently the data is sent!

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that the process of opening a connection takes time and it can cause some performance issues. That´s the main reason to use connection pools. But there are cases where creating a connection every time is not a big deal and might keep your code simpler.